# Simple date class in Java

Tags: java, date, time, calendar

Is there a date class in Java which I can construct with a year, month, day, hour, minute, second and millisecond and then do comparisons which give the number of milliseonds between two date values, ignoring things like daylight saving, leap seconds etc? Can I use the Calendar class for this? I was thinking about doing that, but it talks about leap seconds and daylight saving, and I don't want that to affect the calculations.

It is important that the following invariant holds true all the times:

For all y1, y2, m1, m2, d1, d2, h, m, s, ms:

```
(
    f(y1, m1, d1, h, m, s, ms).getTimeInMillis() - 
    f(y2, m2, d2, h, m, s, ms).getTimeInMillis()
) 
% 
(24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) == 0
```

I basically need to know what the function f should be.

Comment: If you use `Calendar` with local time zone, does it still apply leap seconds? (For local time zone you can use your own instance of `SimpleTimeZone` if there is no useful value in JDK -- i don't remember).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try using Joda DateTime where you could do

```
DateTime d1 = new DateTime(y1,m1,d1,h1,m1,s1,ms1);
DateTime d2 = new DateTime(y2,m2,d2,h2,m2,s2,ms2);
long delta = d1.toMillis() - d2.toMillis();
```

Also consider:

```
 DateTime d1 = new DateTime(y1,m1,d1,h1,m1,s1,ms1);
 DateTime d2 = new DateTime(y2,m2,d2,h2,m2,s2,ms2);
 Duration delta = new Duration( d1, d2);
 int days = delta.toPeriod().getDays();
```

If you have unusual needs you may want to look at Joda Chronology objects.

Comment: This does not give what the OP asked. I tried `DateTime d1 = new DateTime(2024, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);` and `DateTime d2 = new DateTime(2024, 3, 24, 0, 0, 0, 0);`. In my time zone (Europe/Copenhagen) I got a `delta` of 687 600 000. `delta % (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)`should be equal to 0, but it is 82 800 000, equal to 23 hours.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use the Calendar class for your calculations. You can construct your dates and use `getTimeInMillis()` for comparison.

I would also recommend a [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) java library which has a lot of functionality for dates. It has a better performance as well.

Comment: Does the calendar year/month/day/hour/minute/second constructor ignore daylight savings?

Comment: @Clinton No, if your default time zone has summer time (DST), `Calendar` would take it into account, so the answer is not correct. Other than that, while using `Calendar` was reasonable in 2011, no one should use that class any more since it had severe design problems and has been outdated the last 10 years.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Calendar class to set your year, month and other stuff.

Look at the `calendar.set()` and the `calendar.getTime(`) methods' javadocs.

Then, `date.getTime()` will give you the absolute milliseconds from 1970.

Answer (score 1):

### tl;dr

Use *java.time* classes in modern Java.

```java
Duration
.between(
    LocalDateTime.of( year, month, dayOfMonth, hour, minute ) ,
    LocalDateTime.of( year, month, dayOfMonth, hour, minute )
)
.toMillis()
```

**Beware:** Use of `LocalDateTime` does *not* account for real-world anomalies found with time zones. The code above assumes generic 24-hour days. But with time zones, days can be 23 hours long, 25 hours long, or other lengths.

### Avoid legacy date-time classes

Avoid using the terribly flawed `Calendar` class. That class is part of the legacy date-time classes that were supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

### *java.time*

#### Time zone

Your code neglected to specify a time zone. Therefore, `Calendar` implicitly applied the JVM’s current default time zone.

I suggest not relying upon such an implicit default. Specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly, even if you do want the default.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
```

Or:

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;
```

#### `ZonedDateTime`

To represent a moment as seen in a particular time zone, use the `ZonedDateTime` class with its [`of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#of(int,int,int,int,int,int,int,java.time.ZoneId)) method.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( year, month, dayOfMonth, hour, minute, second, nanoOfSecond, zoneId ) ;
```

The `ZonedDateTime` class accounts for the anomalies that come with time zones, such as [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).

#### `LocalDateTime`

But you said specifically you want to ignore time zone anomalies. For that, use the `LocalDateTime` class. This class ignores time zone rules.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of( year, month, dayOfMonth, hour, minute ) ;
```

To calculate elapsed time, use `Duration` class.

```
Duration duration = Duration.between( someLdt , otherLdt ) ;
```

You want to know the elapsed time in milliseconds.

```
long milliseconds = duration.toMillis() ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use long. But you still have to worry about leap days.  You can do comparisons like.

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis(); // nanoTime is better for benchmarks
// do something.
long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
```

However, if you have to consider leap years etc. Calendar may be the best choice as dates are naturally messy ;)  You could consider JodaTime library which is nicer but not much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DateUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html) for date manipulation. There is also entire [new API since Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html).

Comment: Link only answers are seldom useful. Fortunately there’s [a new answer by Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78045755/5772882) spelling out how the new API since Java 8 answers the question.